# Packed meat unrefrigerated storage

Tags: food-safety, meat, raw-meat

I have a 1kg beef brisket, still in store packaging, sitting at room temp for 24 hours. Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not safe it has exceeding USDA time and temperature guidelines.

See the following for guidelines

http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/danger-zone-40-f-140-f/ct_index